# Selecting hosting provider and service for site like KhanAcademy

Tags: hosting, web-hosting, cloudflare, host

I'm having difficulties with selecting a host for a website that I'm working on and would appreciate some sincere tips. There are a lot of articles on the topics, many of which are biased, which is why I'm quite confused.

I need help selecting a specific host and service. I have the following requirements and would like a few different suggestions. Ideally, I want one suggestion on a specific service with Cloudflare since that's my primary choice even though I find their offering confusing. I also would like one suggestion with a provider that accepts BTCs as payment.

Now to my requirements:
The website is quite similar to KhanAcademy and Udemy. We want to host about 75 GB of videos that users should be able to view directly on the site (stream) with our own mediaplayer.

We also have about 15 GB of audios that users should be play directly on the site and download.

We do NOT want to use YouTube, Soundcloud or similar services.

Finally, we have an additional 25 GB of files that we need to host, and that users should be able to download.

The media should load quickly but since the site is new, we have no idea of bandwidth requirement. However, we expect that they will be slow at first but grow steadily over time.

We want the hosting service to come with SSL.

And we want a three-year subscription with a fixed upfront fee rather than monthly payments

Although this isn't a must, but we would prefer if we could use the same hosting service for two separate websites with different domains.

Comment: Is the following the answer you are looking for, or does it help to specify your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/54792557/8575607

Comment: @mythenmetz Thank you for your reply. Not really. The post is quite technical and described the technology while I would like to know more about specific services..Don't know how much more detailed I could be. Is there something in particular that you're wondering?

Comment: A Ghamidi: If you want to configure the server yourself, what you will have to if you are not using a managed service as "YouTube, Soundcloud or similar services", you will have to go into technical details on how you want your site to be load balanced to manage it yourself. And as long as you have not decided on the technology you want to work with, any recommendation is pointless. Btw. recommendations are a bit difficult on this site, so technical details are the ones you get the better help here anyway.

Comment: A Ghamidi: I could make a long shot assuming you would want to use a CDN, referring you to this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network#Notable_content_delivery_service_providers , where virtually every offer is of course slightly different and you will have to decide yourself whether that works for you. Or do you want a simple hosting service that you then overlay with a Reverse Proxy like Cloudflare? There exists nearly an infinite amount of basic webhosting providers - you could e.g. look for ones in your country to support local businesses.

Comment: @mythenmetz Alright, so technical advice then. As you can tell, I'm at the early stages and would like help with selecting a technology that fits above requirements and is not too expensive. And I'm aware that there are infinite amount of basic webhosting providers but I can't really trust online reviews because of affiliate marketing and shady "marketing" tactics. So a traditional hosting service with a reverse proxy would be less expensive than Cloudflare's video streaming service? Do I need to think about anything in particular when setting it up?

Comment: @mythenmetz This isn't my territory and I'm looking for the least expensive solution that achieves the above, especially decent bandwidth

Comment: A Ghamidi: Oh, so you were talking about Cloudflares managed solution "Cloudflare Stream". I was not aware of that. If you look for managed server offerings, I am probably the wrong person to ask. It might nevertheless be the best decision for you, because you then do not have to take care about adaptive players and setting everything up (which might take considerably long). I know that Akamai has a similar offering, and that's where my knowledge ends. Typically these offerings are made by CDNs, so you might want to scroll through the list linked above and check them for streaming offerings.